# Using percentage with position attribute of a box

Tags: css

Can i use percentage values with position attribute?
My CSS code

```
div {
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Is above CSS code valid?

Comment: Of course. Other values are em, rem, px.

Comment: .pos_fixed {
position:relative;
top:-80%;
right:-10%;
border-radius:4%;
background:lightgreen;
border-color:black;
}
.firstparapos {
position:relative;
top: 80%;
right: -20%;
}

Comment: But when i use percentage in my CSS code its not working but it works fine when i use px (pixel) instead of %.